# Subroutine to connect to MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, subroutine

I have this subroutine setup to connect to a MS Access database:

```
Public Sub MakeDBConnection(ByVal source As String)
    Try
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & source & ";")
        cn.Open()
    Catch e As Exception
        ReportError("CRITICAL", e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It is in a module, and any function that uses it in the module it works with, however, when I try and use it from `Main.vb` (my main form) it doesn't seem to do anything, as any tries with executing SQL queries come back with an error saying I must initialize the connection.

I have tried setting all variables it uses to Public, but it doesn't work. Maybe I need to return something? I don't know.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is CN defined? If it is a global variable, this is a very bad approach that is begging to leave connections to your DB open.

Comment: But Jet prefers a single connection that is re-used, particularly because of the huge overhead of creating the LDB file when the connection is opened. Of course, that's not reason not to manage your connection(s) carefully, but using a single persistent one is actually a performance enhancer with Jet, and a perfectly valid practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the scope of variable cn is local to the Sub. You should change this to a Function and return an OleDbConnection object. So the code would look like this:

```
Public Function MakeDBConnection(ByVal source As String) As OleDbConnection
    Try
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & source & ";")
        cn.Open()

        Return cn

    Catch e As Exception
        ReportError("CRITICAL", e.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Calling code would look like this:

```
' For example:
myOleDbCommand.Connection = MakeDBConnection(source)
```

Also consider having the MakeDBConnection function read from the app.config file for the data source, if that fits your architecture.

Comment: I made an edit to the syntax to actually Dim the cn variable :)

Comment: Can you make cn a static variable and initialize it only if it's not already initialized? You'd probably need a mechanism for closing it (e.g., an optional parameter).